# Box2D with SFML object are ovverlapping and going over each other after colliding

Tags: c++, box2d, collision, sfml

I am using Box2D and SFML to create a simple game. However, my object (ball) does not completely lands after it hits the ground. It seems that 50% of the ball has passed through my border, which looks really awkward. Below are some pictures for illustration.

Ball Before:

[image]

Ball After hitting the border at the ground:

[image]

As you can see, 50% of the ball has dissapeared (most probably due to offsets or what). Anyone know how to fix it?

Below are my code for the object creation:

```
    circ_ = sf::CircleShape(radius);
    circ_.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(size.x/2,size.y/2));
    circ_.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 255));
    circ_.setOutlineThickness(1);
    circ_.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);

    bodyDef_.position = b2Vec2(position.x/PIXEL_PER_METER, position.y/PIXEL_PER_METER);
    
    bodyDef_.type = b2_staticBody;
    bodyFixtureDef_.density = 1.0f;
    bodyFixtureDef_.friction = 0.3f;
    bodyFixtureDef_.restitution = 0.8f;
```

Where on my SFML code, I have created the Box2D object using:

```
Ball basketBall(world, basketBallSize, basketBallPos, 0.0, basketBallRadius, false);
```

Where radius = 32.
Anybody could help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you are actually updating the position and you should simply rollback the last update after a collision has been detected. Anyway, it's hard to say, you are not showing enough code...

Answer (score 2):

Box2d uses the center of a circle/polygon shape as position while SFML uses the top left corner of the sprite/shape as position, so you need to take that into account when translating between SFML and Box2d positions. Also keep in mind Box2d uses meters instead of pixles and radians instead of degrees.

Just do like that:

```
#include <cmath> // for M_PI define

Sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(b2BallBody->GetPosition().x * PIXEL_PER_METER - Sprite.getGlobalBounds().width * 0.5f,
                                b2BallBody->GetPosition().y * PIXEL_PER_METER - Sprite.getGlobalBounds().height * 0.5f));
Sprite.setRotation(b2BallBody->GetAngle() * (float)(180.0 / M_PI));
```